# Careers invite preview still using old username

Tags: bug, status-completed, display-names, jobs

I used the public link in the *Share your Invitations* section of http://careers.stackoverflow.com. I pasted the link in a Facebook status message, and the facebook preview displayed the following:

[image]

The problem is that `Harikawashi` has not been my username for some time. I changed my username from `Harikawashi` to `Pieter Muller` via StackOverflow. As far as I can tell, careers.stackoverflow.com knows me as `Pieter Muller`, and I cannot find any references to `Harikawashi` anywhere.

It seems the public invite link preview blurp still references the original username - this should be fixed, as it can be both confusing and embarressing (I believe most of us don't want to be known in professional circles by the chat room handles we chose as teenagers!).

**UPDATE**

I might add that actually following the invite link leads to the page below, which uses my old username as the link - once opened, the `Harikawashi` link does lead to a page using `Pieter Muller` as expected.

[image]

Comment: I would really like a response to this - is it a bug, is it a feature, is it my mistake?

Comment: We're consolidating our user name fields in the near future. That should fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested this, and it has been fixed at some time in the couple of years since this was raised.